# LLevar muuri javascript css a Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, css3

deseo llevar el Código o implementar la siguiente vista a angular 7

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var grid = null,
      wrapper = document.querySelector('.muuri-container'),
      gridElem = wrapper.querySelector('.grid'),
      dragOrder = [];

  // Init the grid layout
  grid = new Muuri(gridElem, {
    dragEnabled: true
  });

});
```

```css
.grid {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 840px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  cursor: move;
}
.item.blue .custom-content {
  background-color: #33A6B8;
}
.item.red .custom-content {
  background-color: #F19483;
}
.item.green .custom-content {
  background-color: #86C166;
}
.item.w2 {
  width: 410px;
}
.item.h2 {
  height: 410px;
}
.item-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.custom-content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.item.muuri-item-dragging {
  z-index: 3;
  transition: none;
}
.item.muuri-item-releasing {
  z-index: 2;
}
@media (max-width: 877px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(33.33% - 11px);
    height: calc(33.33vw - 11px);
  }
  .item.w2 {
    width: calc(33.33% - 11px);
  }
  .item.h2 {
    height: calc(33.33vw - 11px);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    height: calc(50vw - 10px);
  }
  .item.w2 {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
  .item.h2 {
    height: calc(50vw - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="muuri-container">
      <h2>Generación Nuevo Conocimiento</h2>
      <div class="muuri-header filter-controls">

      </div><!-- /.muuri-header -->

      <div class="grid">

        <div class="item blue" data-color="blue" data-title="02">
          <div class="item-content">
            <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
            <div class="custom-content">
              <b>Artículos</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- item -->

        <div class="item red" data-color="red" data-title="02">
          <div class="item-content">
            <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
            <div class="custom-content">
              <b> Resultado de investigación</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- item -->

        <div class="item green" data-color="gren" data-title="02">
          <div class="item-content">
            <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
            <div class="custom-content">
              <b>Capítulos en libros resultado

                de investigación</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- item -->

      </div><!-- /.grid -->

    </div><!-- /.muuri-container -->
 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.3.1/web-animations.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/muuri@0.8.0/dist/muuri.min.js"></script>
```

trate de implementar y seguir los pasos de esta [pagina](https://www.npmjs.com/package/muuri-angular) pero no me resulto con lo que copie en el codigo

Comment: Te puede servir algo mas poderoso que esa libreria de muuri.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Comment: @AlexisNarvaez gracias por el aporte pero el proyecto esta en Boostrap y si tengo que instalar material seria un espagueti de librerias, ademas exigieron que fuera con esa libreria

Comment: por que espagueti si puedes modular perfectamente...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue instalar los [paquetes](https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/muuri-angular) en angular de muuri y web-animation y colocar los css de la pregunta que hice y listo!!

este es el [Resultado](https://angular-muuributons.stackblitz.io)